# How put AngularJS + AngularJS UI (Utils + Bootstrap) into Grails?

Tags: angularjs, grails, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ui-utils

I need to put into Grails 2.4.4 this:

- [AngularJS v1.3.15](https://angularjs.org/)
- [AngularJS UI Utils v0.2.3](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)
- [AngularJS UI Bootstrap v0.2.11](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
- [Bootstrap CSS v3.3.4](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) (needed by AngularJS UI Bootstrap)
- JQuery? not sure if needed

I saw some plugins for Grails that add AngularJS but none that add AngularJS UI's. How to simply put this together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adopting AngularJS as your front-end single-page framework, and Grails as your REST API server, for the separation of concerns I would adopt a separate package manager like [bower](http://bower.io/) for managing the dependencies that are required on the client side and use Grails plugins only for managing server-side dependencies. At some point Grails might become a bottleneck for managing client-side plugins.

It does not necessarily imply that you cannot automate the process of dependency management by using task runners like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) as this interesting [blog post](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/manage-javascript-library-dependencies-via-bower-in-grails/) points out.

Comment: If I understand correctly, after downloading packages by bower into `web-app/bower-components`, I don't need to change anything in grails for him to see AngularJS packages? Honestly, my project isn't big so I suppose that I don't need separate package manager.

Comment: if you are using the [asset-pipeline-plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) you should put your static assets under grails-app/assets/javascripts. you can reference your assets in your .gsps with this syntax: `<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>`. If you don't mind hosting these static assets you might consider using a CDN.

Comment: I hope my original post did answer your question by the way.

Comment: For now I'll try CDN and include them in layout. This would be simplest way I suppose. Thanks for help ;]